# Keep string after first number

Tags: regex, r

This seems like it should be easy but I can't figure out which permutation of regex matching will result in extracting the whole string **after** the first number if the string. I can extract the string before the first number like so:

```
gsub( "\\d.*$", "", "DitchMe5KeepMe" )
```

Any idea how to write the regex pattern such that the string after the first number is kept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of lazy dot matching, I'd rely on a `\D` non-digit character class and use `sub` to make just one replacement:

```
sub( "^\\D*\\d", "", "DitchMe5KeepMe" )
```

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of a string
- `\D*` - matches zero or more non-digits
- `\d` - matched a digit

NOTE: to remove up to the first *number*, add a `+` after the last `\d` to match one or more digits.

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/x93sDh).

Comment: Hi, is there a way to keep the number? So the output is "5KeepMe"?

Comment: @Mari Sure, use a capturing group in the pattern and a backreference in the replacement, `sub( "^\\D*(\\d)", "\\1", "DitchMe5KeepMe" )`. Or use a PCRE regex with a lookahead: `sub( "^\\D*(?=\\d)", "", "DitchMe5KeepMe", perl=TRUE)`. See [this R demo online](https://ideone.com/vkZFy2).

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

What I can see is that you want to remove everything until the first number, so you can use this regex and replace it with an empty string:

```
^.*?\d
```

I used `.*?` to make the pattern ungreedy, so if you had `DitchMe5Keep8Me` it will match `DitchMe5`, if you use a greedy pattern like `.*\d` it would match `DitchMe5Keep8`

**[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS7rI5/3)**

**[R Fiddle Demo](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=QBlnJLew&version=2)**

[image]

Comment: I would like to remove everything before AND including the first number but ONLY the first number. So while this works wonderfully: `gsub( ".*?\\d", "", "DitchMe5KeepMe" )`, this: `gsub( ".*?\\d", "", "Dit5chMe5KeepMe" )` does not produce the expected output of "chMe5KeepMe" and rather just "KeepMe"

Comment: @boshek, I've updated the answer. To make the trick I used the anchor `^`

Comment: The trick is to use `sub`. There is only one replacement expected, so there is no point using `gsub`. See my answer. The anchor is a must anyway.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nice, thanks for the comment. Never used R

Comment: Hi, is there a way to keep the number? So the output is "5KeepMe"?

Comment: @Mari yes, you have to use capturing groups and replacement string. `gsub("^.*?(\\d)", "$1", "DitchMe5KeepMe")`. Here you have a sample https://regex101.com/r/MY3csF/1

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("DitchMe5KeepMe", "(?<=\\d).*$")
[1] "KeepMe"
```

which will extract everything after the first digit.

```
str_extract("DitchMe5KeepMe6keepme", "(?<=\\d).*$")
[1] "KeepMe6keepme"
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to keep the number? So the output is "5KeepMe"?