# Remove numbers and everything after in strings

Tags: r, regex

I have receipt data and I want to aggregate the items which are the same product type; for example, milk, cheeses, jams. At the moment, the data includes specifics like pack size and price if the item is flashed as a special offer. I want to remove this specific info from the end of the string and just have everything before the numbers kept.

For example:

```
    Dairy Milk 3Litre
    Brown Onions 1KG
    Avocado 2 AT 3.00 EACH
```

I want to remove everything after and including the numbers. I want to be left with Dairy Milk,Brown Onions, Avocado etc.

Comment: see this post as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612262/remove-string-after-first-number-using-r-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` here to remove everything after first digit occurs

```
x <- c("Dairy Milk 3Litre","Brown Onions 1KG","Avocado 2 AT 3.00 EACH")

sub("\\d+.*", "", x)
#[1] "Dairy Milk "   "Brown Onions " "Avocado "
```

or the other way round, extract everything before first digit occurs.

```
sub("(.*?)\\d+.*", "\\1", x)
```